Is this a valid proof of Lemma 17.2 in Boolos' Computability & Logic?
Silly question. I have decided to reopen Boole's Computability and Logic and I'm wondering if there is a (very slightly) different way of proving Lemma 17.2, which states $\def\bg{\textbf{g}}$

17.2 Lemma. Let $T$ be a consistent theory extending $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the set of Gödel numbers of theorems in $T$ is not definable in $T$.

The proof makes use of the Diagonal Lemma, which states that for any formula $B(y)$ there is a sentence $G$ such that $\vdash_T G\leftrightarrow B (\bg)$ where $\bg$ is the Gödel numeral of $G$.
Proof (?) of 17.2: Let $T$ be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $\theta(y)$ defines the set $\Theta$ of Gödel numbers of sentences in $T$. By the diagonal lemma, there is a sentence $G$ such that $\vdash_T G \leftrightarrow \sim \theta(\ulcorner G \urcorner).$ Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{not } &  T\vdash G && \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ && \\
\text{ if and only if } & 
g \notin \Theta && && \text{ by definition of $\Theta$}\\
\text{ if and only if } & 
T \vdash \sim \theta\left(\bg\right) && && \text{ by $\theta(x)$ defining $\Theta$}\\
\text{ if and only if } & 
T \vdash G && && \text{ by $\vdash_T G \leftrightarrow \sim \theta(\bg)$}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and thus $T$ proves $G$ and does not prove $G$, which is impossible, so our initial assumption of $\Theta$ being definable is wrong.
Is the argument above correct?

The proof in the book, in case it is needed:

Let $T$ be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $\theta(y)$ defines the set $\Theta$ of Gödel numbers of sentences in $T$. By the diagonal lemma, there is a sentence $G$ such that
$$\vdash_T G \leftrightarrow \sim \theta(\ulcorner G \urcorner).$$
In other words, letting $g$ be the Gödel number of $G$, and $\bg$ its Gödel numeral, we have
$$\vdash_T G \leftrightarrow \sim \theta(\bg).$$
Then $G$ is a theorem of $T$. For if we assume $G$ is not a theorem of $T$, then $g$ is not in $\Theta$, and since $\theta(y)$ defines $\Theta$, we have $\vdash_T \sim \theta(\bg)$; but then, since $\vdash_T G \leftrightarrow \sim \theta(\bg)$, we have $\vdash_T G$ and $G$ is a theorem of $T$ after all. But since $G$ is a theorem of $T$, $g$ is in $\Theta$, and so we have $\vdash_T \theta(\bg)$; but then, since $\vdash_T G \leftrightarrow \sim \theta(\bg)$, we have $\vdash_T \sim G$, and $T$ is inconsistent.


I think the only issue is the justification of the second step, which also involves the consistency of $T$.
